# Is it technically correct to describe normal figures and text figures as upper case and lower case numbers?

Tags: word-usage, numbers

There is a recent question on the Graphic Design SE asking: [Why don't upper case numbers exist?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54423/why-dont-upper-case-numbers-exist)

There is also a heavily upvoted answer saying that upper and lower case numbers do exist, and that what I've found to be called *"Text Figures"* are in fact a lower case version of numbers.

Example of upper vs lower case from question:

[image]

This doesn't make sense to me for too many reasons to list here, and I'm worried that it's a perpetuation of misinformation. I think "lower case" should only be a colloquial description to make it easy to describe in conversation, but the definitions do not reconcile.

However, I'm not an English or Number History(?) Specialist, so I can't be 100% sure. I'd actually be happy to be wrong.

**Can anyone tell me if this is a correct way to describe these concepts?**

Comment: No. It's not about the **position** of the character with respect to the base line that distinguishes "uppercase" and "lowercase." By definition, *case* applies to alphabets (letters) only. In case of alphabets, the character shape significantly varies cf. *A* and *a.* They are called so by the printing trade because in the hand compositing days, the "capital" letters were stored in the upper drawer (case) and the "small" ones in the lower. See "case" (letter case) at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case

Comment: However, in typography design, the terms "uppercase" and  "lowercase" are used by some as synonyms for *Lining numerals* and *Old-Style numerals* See: http://www.6picas.com/numerals/ See also: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=NruUsGqAcSAC&pg=PT429&lpg=PT429&dq=%22uppercase+numerals%22&source=bl&ots=zZycZzeGGW&sig=RlHF86qsVU1aAL4CkXR-IiAclxA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FPZyVdT2JI2TuASZoYagDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22uppercase%20numerals%22&f=false

Comment: @Kris thanks, that seems like the foundations of an answer, but you've given arguments both for and against, and those resources citing it as true aren't exactly canonical imo.

Comment: @Kris The problem is that that applies to the numbers as well: the lining numbers were frequently placed in the upper case along with uppercase letters, and by that logic they are ‘uppercase’ numbers. From a purely shape-based (and typographer-drawer-position-based) perspective, it makes good sense to see lining numbers as the uppercase equivalents of text numbers. But from a usage perspective, it makes no sense, since the functional difference between upper- and lowercase letters is entirely orthogonal to the difference in usage between lining and text figures. [cont’d→]

Comment: [→cont’d] As is so often the case with “is this correct?” questions regarding language, it depends: _correct to whom?_ To me, the answer to this question is no—calling them upper- and lowercase numbers is utterly foreign to me, and makes little sense. To me, the terms ‘uppercase’ and ‘lowercase’ are today deeply entrenched in their _functional_, rather than their _formal_, perspective. But since there are no authorities to label something uniformly correct or incorrect, personal opinions like that are probably about as good as we can get on this.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I appreciate your input, and lack of a downvote :) but I think that for Stack Exchange to be an authoritative resource it should be held to standards of accuracy. It would be fine to label them like this, and then state that it is a typography-specific description. Instead, a mod no less, has categorically stated that these are upper and lower case numbers, and so anyone who doesn't know more will just leave with that definitive fact, which ultimately is incorrect (I think, hence my question).

Comment: @Dom I think your question here is a very good one (and one I asked myself when reading Vincent’s answer). I don’t think an authoritative answer can be found unless someone can circumstantially prove that this usage has or has not been in common use in the typesetting world, but that doesn’t mean the question is not good; similarly, I don’t think an authoritative answer to the GD question can be found, but the question itself I find a good one.

Comment: As @Janus already mentioned: This question is not answerable without a good specification as to what you consider technically correct. Even then, we will likely find that your actual question is off-topic as it is, e.g., about history instead. The only answer we can give here, in particular as your question stands, is something along the lines of: *Those who care about the difference tend to use the descriptors* upper- *and* lowercase. *Hence, they seem to be established technical terms. Hence, they are as correct as they can possibly be.* However, this is probably not what you want.

Comment: Dom, that was exactly my point: "arguments both for and against, and those resources citing it as true aren't exactly canonical" -- the argument for is supported, authentic and accepted; the one against is an exceptional usage, which in fact is essentially metaphorical: "just like we have in alphabets" and not even a recorded official definition or usage.

Comment: Btw, Dom, it's Mr S commenting there, not Mrs :)

Comment: @MrStupid The top answer on that post is just not correct notwithstanding the fact that it garnered a huge number of up votes, obviously because of the surprising details it gives, not because it is correct. You may want to delete the part of your comment that says "This question is already **answered**" for that reason.

Comment: @Kris I can not edit that comment now because I commented yesterday.

Comment: @MrStupid We can always post a fresh (or revised) comment & delete the earlier one. (Just in case you wanted to know.)

Comment: Relate to typography numbers [Why don't upper case numbers exist?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54423/why-dont-upper-case-numbers-exist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a. *Printing*. On a compositor's frame: either of two shallow trays divided into compartments in order to hold printing type.

If a set did indeed have different *sorts* for the different types of digits, then the equal-height digits would be in the upper case and the differing-height digits would be in the lower case.

> b. *Typogr*. Each of the two forms, capital or minuscule, in which a letter of the alphabet may be written or printed.

A majuscule form has a generally equal or near-equal size for the different glyphs, with their generally reaching from the base line to the cap-height bar perhaps some curves reaching slightly above or below that to give a better sense of balance (so that they look like they are going from the base line to the cap-height). This is true of the equal-height digits.

A minuscule form varies in height, with some perhaps reaching up to the ascender height (or perhaps just the cap height) and some reaching down to the descender height. This is true of the different-height digits.

We can also consider the uses. When different-height digits are used they are used in runs of text, where one also uses minuscule letters. When using such digits one would generally still use equal-height digits if used with text that was capitalised.

Really, in any use that makes use of these, digits are bicameral and the equal-height digits are correctly called "upper case" or *majuscule* while the different-height digits are correctly called "lower case" or *minuscule*. There's no technical argument for calling them anything else.

In a use that doesn't make use of them, digits are unicameral. It still make sense to refer to digits as "upper case" or *majuscule*, because of the history of how they came into fonts, and also because many fonts do have lower-case digits in them, albeit not easily available to users with most applications.

Comment: I just saw this answer now. I’m guessing your quotes are from a dictionary definition of _case_, but could you edit in more detail/links? As for usage, I have to disagree that there is no argument for calling them anything else. By far the most common usage of uppercase letters today is to capitalise proper nouns, sentences, and various other words; lining numbers are **never** used for this purpose. You may use lining numbers with text written all in lining (i.e., uppercase) letters, but in normal writing, a name like _42nd Street_ would never be written with a lining 4 and an oldstyle 2.